# Querying transactions per account in Parity

Tags: parity

I know `geth` doesn't provide the functionality of querying transactions of a particular account. But, does Parity provide it? Kind of a javascript function like this:

```
getAllAccountTransactions(account_address)
```

with the output being transaction hashes.

Comment: Why can't you query those transactions using Etherscan API? Or is it on a private chain?

Comment: @Andrey , Well, I don't need to, since I have my own blockchain explorer, which is SQL based and I can get everything from there. I am just asking to increase my general knowledge. Parity is kind of `ahead of geth` revolutionary software, so they should have this included. Or at least it should be "planned" task, imho.